# Comparing values of current period and prior period where the current period value is blank

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am doing a comparison and everything works except when the current value is blank for the CY but not blank for the PY.

Any thoughts?

```
Mat Usage Sum = 
SUMX(
    VALUES('All data new'[Component Material]),
    CALCULATE(
        SUMX(
            VALUES('All data new'[Component Description]),
            [YOY Component Diff]
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply ckeck for blank values and chose a default value:

```
Mat Usage Sum = 
IF(
  SUMX(
      VALUES('All data new'[Component Material]),
      CALCULATE(
        SUMX(
            VALUES('All data new'[Component Description]),
            [YOY Component Diff]
            )
       )
  ) = BLANK(), 
"Blank",
"Not Blank"
)
```